# I have an array of objects, I want to only get back the values that match (region)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set up a function, that when the tab is clicked it shows only that region, EX. 'US', 'EU', etc. I'm already mapping to show the whole array, but I also need it to show only the selected region when that region is selected.
This is my JS logic (which really isnt much) and the tabs that hold the value.

```js
  const showRegion = () =>  {
    if(selectedTab === 'us') {
      console.log(vendors.data.region)
    }
    if(selectedTab === 'ca') {
      console.log('YOU HIT THE ca TAB')
    }
    if(selectedTab === 'cb') {
      console.log('YOU HIT THE cb TAB')
    }
    if(selectedTab === 'eu') {
      console.log('YOU HIT THE eu TAB')
    }
    if(selectedTab === 'top') {
      console.log('YOU HIT THE top TAB')
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">

  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(query.get('region') ?? 'all')
  
    <TabUnstyled
                  className={selectedTab === 'all' ? 'active' : ''}
                  value="all"
                  id="All"
                >
                  {width > 500 ? 'All Vendors' : 'All'}
                </TabUnstyled>
                <TabUnstyled
                  className={selectedTab === 'us' ? 'active' : ''}
                  value="us"
                  id="US"
                  
                >
                  {width > 500 ? 'United States Vendors' : 'United States'}
                </TabUnstyled>
                <TabUnstyled
                  className={selectedTab === 'ca' ? 'active' : ''}
                  value="ca"
                  id="CA"
                >
                  {width > 500 ? 'Canada-USD Vendors' : 'Canada-USD'}
                </TabUnstyled>
                <TabUnstyled
                  className={selectedTab === 'cb' ? 'active' : ''}
                  value="cb"
                  id="CB"
                >
                  {width > 500 ? 'Canada-CAD Vendors' : 'Canada-CAD'}
                </TabUnstyled>
                <TabUnstyled
                  className={selectedTab === 'eu' ? 'active' : ''}
                  value="eu"
                  id="EU"
                >
                  {width > 500 ? 'Europe Vendors' : 'Europe'}
                </TabUnstyled>
                <TabUnstyled
                  className={selectedTab === 'top' ? 'active' : ''}
                  value="top"
                  id="topVendorTab"
                >
                  {width > 500 ? 'Top Ocean Vendors' : 'Top Ocean'}
                </TabUnstyled>




</script>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `filter()` function on arrays?

Comment: @David yes, but I would also have to make a .map() for each region right?

Comment: Would you?  For what purpose?  Note that the code shown has no arrays, doesn't use `.map()` at all, and generally doesn't display any data.  How are you trying to filter your data and display it, and what isn't working?

Comment: @David the data what im trying to map is from a database. I'm already mapping through the whole array of objects. In that database it has a value which is the region. 'us', 'eu', etc.

Comment: Ok, and it sounds like you're asking how to filter that array into a subset of itself before displaying it, right?  So you'd use `.filter()` on that array and then use `.map()` on its result.  You are encouraged to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the data from the database, you should be getting an array of regions. You can use that array to iterate through and then render the tabs in a loop as follows:

I'm going to assume your data to resemble the following for the sake of explanation:

```
const regionData = [
    { regionId: 'all', regionName: 'All', regionFullName: 'All Vendors' },
    { regionId: 'us', regionName: 'United States', regionFullName: 'United States Vendors' },
    { regionId: 'ca', regionName: 'Canada-USD', regionFullName: 'Canada-USD Vendors' },
    { regionId: 'cb', regionName: 'Canada-CAD', regionFullName: 'Canada-CAD Vendors' },
    { regionId: 'eu', regionName: 'Europe', regionFullName: 'Europe Vendors' },
    { regionId: 'top', regionName: 'Top Ocean', regionFullName: 'Top Ocean Vendors' },
];
```

Your component can use this `regionData` like this with some click handler to do some stuff when clicked:

```
{regionData.map(region => (
    <TabUnstyled className={selectedTab === region.regionId ? 'active' : ''} value={region.regionId} id={region.regionId} onClick={() => showRegion(region)}>
        {width > 500 ? region.regionFullName : region.regionName}
    </TabUnstyled>
))}
```

Your click handler can be something like

```
const showRegion = (region) => {
    // do some stuff using region
}
```